# Where do I enter "domain" in remote desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, domain

I'm trying to connect to a remote desktop. They gave me

1. computer name
2. domain
3. username
4. password

Now where/how should I enter "domain"?
[image]

If I don't enter any, I can't connect ("your credentials are not recognized...").

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Enter the domain in the User Name box as *domain*\username or username@*domain*.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting a "Windows does not specify the name specified in the computer name field. Verify that the name is typed correctly, and try again" error when putting a domain followed by a backslash in there. Which is weird because I launch several programs with admin access using a domain prefix for the username (same domain). Then Remote Desktop immediate tries to connect to a computer named "domain" and fails (tries to connect to whatever I put as the domain, before the backslash). I dunno why this is doing this, ARGHHHH.

Answer (score 13):

The domain can go before the UserName to indicate what domain you are logging into.

For computer, enter the computer details they gave you.

So, for Username enter (include the backslash)

```
domain\username
```

The password is a password and you'll be prompted after you click connect!

Comment: This worked for me